# Clarification about Azurite Channeler in Ascension: Deliverance

Tags: ascension

The card text of Azurite Channeler in Ascension: Deliverance states:

"Banish a card in your hand and replace it with a Mystic or Heavy Infantry".

Does the replacement card go straight into hand, or does it go into the discard pile?

It seems quite a powerful effect to upgrade one of the base deck cards straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way cards like that work in general is you place the card where the banished card came from. An example of this is Guide of Lost Souls from Dawn of Champions

> You may banish a card in your hand or discard pile. If you do, replace it with a Mystic or Heavy Infantry

When using this card in the iOS app the replacement card goes into your hand if the banished card came from your hand or into your discard if the card came from there. While most other cards specify placing them in your hand I think the replacement text means to put the new card in the same place as the other one came from.

I am unable to find anything in the rules or faq in regard to this but I can confirm this is how the iOS app treats the action.

Comment: Great, thanks. Couldn't find anything in the rules or FAQ either.